# RegEx to bring in data after characters with and without spaces

Tags: regex

I need to capture the data after the "AP" and before the first space in the data.  I've noticed that the data can look like the below where there can be a space or no space after the AP.  Here is the expression I am using:  (?<=AP)(\S+)(?=\s)

**Original Data:**

```
AP 1735 2/2/2023 AAA Business Advisors,
AP1735 2/2/2023 AAA Business Advisors,
AP W1735 2/2/2023 AAA Business Advisors,
APW1735 2/2/2023 AAA Business Advisors,
```

I've tried this expression:  (?<=AP)(\S+)(?=\s).  I'm expecting the below results.

```
1735
1735
W1735
W1735
```

Comment: Is something wrong with just `^AP ?(.*?) `?

Comment: Why not just include the space in your match then trim the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use capturing group you can try:

```
(?:(?<=AP)|(?<=AP ))\S+
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/LGQs1v/1)

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using a capture group, you can match AP followed by optional whitespace chars, and then capture 1 or more non whitespace chars in group 1

```
\bAP\s*(\S+)\s
```

**Explanation**

- `\bAP` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match, then match AP
- `\s*` Match optional whitespace chars
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1**, match 1+ non whitespace chars
- `\s` Match a whitespace char

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v9Eo0q/1)